# Joomla 3.3 anchor does not download a uploaded pdf

Tags: html, joomla

I my joomla website I have a anchor that points to a uploaded pdf like this

```
<a href="X:\path_to_website\media\contentbuilder\upload\content_downloads\whatever.pdf" download="Folheto Poste Inteligente PT" class="downitem">STUFF</a>
```

When I click it, the file does not download. However, if I "copy link address" and paste it in the address bar, it already works.
What is the cause of this? Some joomla limitation?

Comment: Dammn.. You need to specify file path of *server location of file* and not of your HDD path. e.g. `<a href="http://server/media/contentbuilder/upload/content_downloads/whatever.pdf" download="Folheto Poste Inteligente PT" class="downitem">STUFF</a>`

Comment: That's a link generated by the plugin "content builder". I grab it from the DB and place it in the anchor.I was hoping that there was a way to make this work temporarily before starting to put my hands on the plugin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way a link to a `PDF` is handled is often determined by the browser and the presence of plugins for PDF's. Most browsers handle them inline, i.e. they display them in the page.

Given that you're already using the [HTML5 `download` attribute](http://caniuse.com/#feat=download), it may be that your webpage or browser are the issue or the server configuration. Also wiht the combinations of browsers, plugins etc you may not be able to guarentee the same result across all users.

Things you can try, include:

1. Setting a `target="_blank"` on the `<a href>` tag (not strictly necessary but it will stop the user from leaving the page).
2. setting various headers on the PDF files (e.g. via `.htaccess` if you're using Apache)

For example you could add this to your `.htaccess`

```
<FilesMatch "\.pdf$">
  AddType application/octet-stream .pdf
  Header set Content-Disposition attachment
</FilesMatch>
```